# convert map of custom object to json object?

Tags: javascript, java, json, dictionary

In java , i have a hashmap like below

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> = new HashMap<String, List<Employee>>();
```

I need to convert the above map to json object

**What I tried:-**

used `jsonObject` instead of `HashMap` and `JsonArray` instead of `list`

```
 com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject  jsonObject = new com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject();
 com.amazonaws.util.json.JsonArray empList = new JsonArray();
 empList.add(empObject)
 jsonObject.put("some String", empList);
```

Then add `jsonObject`  in request attribute

```
 request.setAttribute("empMap", jsonObject.toString() );
```

but when i retrieve it in javascript i get the value of jsonObject

```
  {emp_10:[com.val.Emp@4b7b4bc5]}
```

As you can see above  i get the value `com.val.Emp@4b7b4bc5` not its properties why so  ?

**Also Is there a better way where i can convert the hashmap of custom object** i.e `Map<String, List<Employee>>` to json object without using
jsonObject instead of HashMap and JsonArray instead of list?

I am using already below libraries in my project and open to use any new one if required

```
Jettison Library (org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject)
json-lib(net.sf.json.JSONObject)
apache json library (com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject)
```

Comment: implement the toString(), as it seems default toString is being called and returning the object reference

Comment: you need to overwrite the toString Method

Comment: @user3198603 - Did you checked my answer? Does it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have an additional helper function at java end

```
public JSONObject asJSON(Employee employee) {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     return new JSONObject(mapper.writeValueAsString(employee));
}
```

and in place of adding `empObject` in following, add the updated value `asJSON(empObject)`

```
 empList.add(empObject)
```

Additionally, remove `.toString()`

```
request.setAttribute("empMap", jsonObject.toString());
```